# How to inherit data from a create within the same store?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I've 2 `create` in the same `function store`, but one field of the 1th `create` it must be the same of a field in the 2th create.

Is it possible?

##### `DataController.php`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        SendData::create($request->validated());

        // How I take here data from firt ::create ??
        $random_data_from_form1 = ??

        $data_from_form2 = $request->input('data_form2');

        SendMoreData::create([
           'field1' => $random_data_from_form1,
           'field2' => $data_from_form2
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue here. If this is about eloquent models then `::create` returns a model instance which you can store in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `create()` method with return a new model instance of `SendData`.

You can update your code like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new_object = SendData::create($request->validated());

        // How I take here data from firt ::create ??
        $random_data_from_form1 = $new_object->your_field;

        $data_from_form2 = $request->input('data_form2');

        SendMoreData::create([
           'field1' => $random_data_from_form1,
           'field2' => $data_from_form2
        ]);
    }
```